# JQuery incorrectly encodes URL set on img src. How can I make it not encode?

Tags: jquery

jQuery has the following behaviour when a new image is created:

```
$('img').attr('src','http://example.com/​notexist.png').appendTo('body')
```

The following error message occurs:

```
GET http://example.com/%E2%80%8Bnotexist.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm expecting the 404s, but the URL is incorrect - **note the extra encoding around the slash** - how can I stop this and have 'src' set properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) character after the slash (encoded as `E2 80 8B` in UTF-8).

You should remove that character. If you have trouble doing that because you cannot see it, consider retyping the whole URL from scratch.

Comment: Oh Christ, you're right! The URL I used in my example was modified from one I scraped, obviously it got simplified but the nasty character never changed. Thank you so much, I never would have spotted this otherwise! *internet hug*

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a character between the '/' and the 'notexist.png', so I believe jQuery does it right. Note how the link isn't highlighted completely in your posting.
According to Chrome Developer Tools, the character is `&#8203;`

Answer (score 1):

As Frédéric mentioned, you have an encoded chars before the file's name, and that's the reason you get that error. You Probably copied that src with those chars from somewhere. you should get rid of the encoded stuff or write the URL by yourself.

But by doing even so your jquery will still fail, even with a valid URL.
The right way to [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) is creating the jquery element first, and then to append it.

Method 1:

```
$('<img src="http://example.com/notexist.png"/>').appendTo('body');
```

Method 2:

```
$('<img />').attr('src','http://example.com/notexist.png').appendTo('body');
```

Here's a jsfiddle link that illustrate the working and non working methods:
http://jsfiddle.net/R7U5H/2/